# Resolve External Unparsed Entity during parsing with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, doctype, dtd-parsing

How can I resolve External Unparsed Entity during parsing with lxml?

Here is my code example:

```
import io

from lxml import etree

content = b"""\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE sample [
<!NOTATION jpeg SYSTEM "image/jpeg">
<!ENTITY ref1 SYSTEM "python-logo-small.jpg" NDATA jpeg>
<!ELEMENT sample EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST sample src ENTITY #REQUIRED>
]>
<sample src="ref1"/>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, resolve_entities=True)
doc = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(content), parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

*Note: I'm using lxml >= 3.4*

Currently I have the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE sample [
<!NOTATION jpeg SYSTEM "image/jpeg" >
<!ENTITY ref1 SYSTEM "python-logo-small.jpg" NDATA jpeg>
<!ELEMENT sample EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST sample src ENTITY #REQUIRED>
]>
<sample src="ref1"/>
```

Here, the `ref1` entity isn't resolved to "python-logo-small.jpg".
I expected to have `<sample src="python-logo-small.jpg"/>`.
Is there something wrong?

I also try with:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, resolve_entities=True, load_dtd=True)
```

But I have the same result.

Alternatively, I'd like to resole the entities myself. To do that, I try to list the entities that way:

```
for entity in doc.docinfo.internalDTD.iterentities():
    msg_fmt = "{entity.name!r}, {entity.content!r}, {entity.orig!r}"
    print(msg_fmt.format(entity=entity))
```

But I only get the entity's and the notation's names, not the entity's definition:

```
'ref1', 'jpeg', None
```

How to access to the entity's definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's impossible to "resolve" external unparsed entities, but we can list them:

```
import io

import xml.sax

content = b"""\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE sample [
<!NOTATION jpeg SYSTEM "image/jpeg">
<!ENTITY ref1 SYSTEM "python-logo-small.jpg" NDATA jpeg>
<!ELEMENT sample EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST sample src ENTITY #REQUIRED>
]>
<sample src="ref1"/>
"""


class MyDTDHandler(xml.sax.handler.DTDHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def unparsedEntityDecl(self, name, publicId, systemId, ndata):
        print(dict(name=name, publicId=publicId, systemId=systemId, ndata=ndata))
        xml.sax.handler.DTDHandler.unparsedEntityDecl(self, name, publicId, systemId, ndata)


parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setDTDHandler(MyDTDHandler())
parser.parse(io.BytesIO(content))
```

The result is:

```
{'systemId': u'python-logo-small.jpg', 'ndata': u'jpeg', 'publicId': None, 'name': u'ref1'}
```

So the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

The XML document with the unparsed entity looks OK. But unparsed entities do not get resolved in the way you seem to expect. If you want to see `<sample src="python-logo-small.jpg"/>` in the parsed output, use an *internal (parsed) entity*.

Example:

```
import io
from lxml import etree

content = b"""\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE sample [
<!ENTITY ref1 "python-logo-small.jpg">
<!ELEMENT sample EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST sample src CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<sample src="&ref1;"/>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, resolve_entities=True)
doc = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(content), parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE sample [
<!ENTITY ref1 "python-logo-small.jpg">
<!ELEMENT sample EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST sample src CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<sample src="python-logo-small.jpg"/>
```

Notes:

- The `ref1` entity is declared as an [internal entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-internal-ent).
- The entity is [referenced](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-entref) with `&ref1;`.
- The `src` attribute is declared as type `CDATA`.

---

You can get the value (URI) of unparsed entities with XSLT, using the [`unparsed-entity-uri`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-unparsed-entity-uri) function. To see it in action, add the following lines to the code example in the question:

```
xsl = etree.XML('''\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="sample">
   <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-entity-uri(@src)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(doc)
print result
```

Output:

```
python-logo-small.jpg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the author of the XML content, so I can't modify it. Is there a way to list the internal entities? Any example with xml.sax.handler?